# how to obtaining alphabet using Huffman Code for given frequency

Tags: computer-science

I am a student and i'm trying to solve this question. But i have trouble with understanding question where to start?

Consider that it is necessary to use Huffman’s algorithm to obtain the encoding of the alphabet {p,q,r} with frequencies fp, fq, fr. In each of the following cases, give an example of frequencies fp, fq, fr that would yield the specified code, if cannot obtain the given code, what is the reason?

```
    (a) p = 0, q = 10,  r = 11          
    (b) p = 0, q = 1,  r = 00 
    (c) p = 10, q = 01,  r = 00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. for explain, i will use below image
[image]

in first tree

```
a = 0
b = 11
c = 11
```

And you can see 1st tree is correct, can obtain code.

in second tree

```
 a = 0
 b = 1
 c = 00
```

There is a **duplicate prefix**(a and c '0' is duplicate). You can see it on the 2nd tree. so cannot obtain given code.

in third tree

```
a = 10
b = 01
c = 00
```

3rd tree is also correct, no duplicate prefix. can obtain code.